# On Entering Text Field set radio button value

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

I use the following code for my radio button and date field

```
<input type="radio" name="datefilter" value="all" checked>All sessions<br>
<input type="radio" name="datefilter" value="after" >
Changes take effect on: 
<input type="text" name="date_filter" value="<? echo date('m-d-Y'); ?>">
```

When the user clicks on the text field, I would like the radio button with the value "after" to be selected, in case the forget to enter the value. I am a php hack, but don't know javascript much at all. If it will make it easier I can definitely add  to the radio fields.

There is already a javascript function running that calls a date picking calendar popup when the user selects the text field. Don't imagine that will

Thanks!

Comment: It would help to know which JS Framework you use. Common Frameworks are: jQuery, prototype or nothing ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add some jQuery to it like this:

[Example page on JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/b7JZX/1/)

Code:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.js">

        <script type="text/javascript">

            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#date_filter').click(function () {
                    $("#after").attr('checked', true);
                });
            });

        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <input type="radio" name="datefilter" value="all" checked>All sessions<br>
        <input type="radio" id="after" name="datefilter" value="after">
        Changes take effect on: 
        <input type="text" id="date_filter" name="date_filter" value="2013-01-01">
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: you're welcome! thats right, the jQuery-script says when clicking on the object with id "date_filter" set object with id "after" as the selected option. you can also refer to objects by the attribute "class". for example: lets say you have multiple options which are all radiobuttions and when you're clicking on the object with id "date_filter" you want all the radiobuttons with same "class"-attribute name to be selected (like this, `<input type="radio" class="after" name="datefilter" value="after">`). you can replace the "#"-tag with a "."-tag, `$(".after").attr('checked', true);`

Comment: so "#id" and ".class" is how one references an object? Great that will be a huge help on several pages!